# Wordpress htaccess constanting creating the same rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Just noticed that the site was showing an internal server error and when checking the .htaccess file found that this was in it around 50 times!

Why would wordpress be creating this rule over and over and over again in .htaccess?

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 </IfModule>
```

This is the URL http://tinyurl.com/qybjyoq

Answer (score 0):

Your Site is not giving any internal server error.

And wordpress .htaccess file is writing the code only one time

Comment: Obviously I fixed the error and removed the extraneous rewrite rules!  My question was more around the cause.  Does anyone know what could have caused this rule to appear in htaccess around 50 times